# Error Domain=AVFoundation ErrorDomain Code=-11819 in iOS 11

Tags: ios, avfoundation, ios11

My video recording screen is going blank and it's throwing an error:

> Error: -11819 Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.

The recording works properly most of the times, but it throws this error mostly when I uninstall the app and reinstall. Can someone help me?

P.S.: This happens in iOS 11 devices only, works perfectly for iOS 10 devices.